# Table View with Countries / States / Cities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am downloading some information from a `JSON` feed about countries, states and their cities. The way I have my final data structure is as follows:

An `NSArray` where each element holds an `NSDictionary`. Each `NSDictionary` has a `key` of the name of the country, and a `value` of an `NSDictionary` corresponding to the states. Each of those `NSDictionary`s hold a `key` of the name of the state and a `value` of an array with a list of the names of the cities.

I want to display each country in a different section in a table view. To return the number of countries (aka. numbeber of sections), I can just do `[countriesArray count]`.

However, to return the number of states and cities of each country, that seems impossible with my current structure. I can access `[countriesArray objectAtIndex:index]`, but after that, how can I access the value of that dictionary (the key is the name of the country)?

Should I restructure my data structures? If so, what's the best way to sort this kind of data?

Comment: Please tell me you have a database in your application? If you are using web calls to drive your UI I have a feeling your app is going to run into more troubles than you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have below data structure which may help.

A container NSArray which has NSDictionary as its object.
Each dictionary has fixed keys like: countryName and stateInfo.
The value of this keys will be: string and NSDictionary.

Each stateInfo dictionary should have fixed keys like: stateName, cities
the value of this keys will be: string and NSarray of cities.

Answer (score 1):

you may handle this problem using the collapsible tableview

from this you can display the relevant data as your requirement.

Comment: collapsible tableview refer from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Reusable-collapsable-table-view-for-iOS

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *countryKeys = [countriesArray allKeys]; //will return you an array of all keys(country names).

Also, instead of doing [countriesArray objectAtIndex:index], you should do [countriesArray valueForKey:[countryKeys objectAtIndex:index]];